# Pourquoi le pronom employé passe-t-il tout à coup de « nous » à « vous » dans la même phrase ?

Tags: pronoms

> Conseiller en image, Kristof décrypte pour **nous** les différents messages que peuvent faire passer les couleurs et **nous** donne quelques clés pour éviter de commettre l’erreur chromatique qui **vous** coûterait le poste.

C'est plutôt insolite de voir un rédacteur ne pas s'en tenir au même pronom « nous » jusqu'au bout.

Comment: A mon avis, c'est une erreur. Une tentative de personnalisation pour vous faire peur et vous inciter à acheter... un livre ?

Comment: Est-ce que vous avez un lien pour l'article en question ? Un peu de contexte pourrait aider avec l'interprétation :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ça peut se défendre, le "nous" pourrait désigner l'ensemble des lecteurs tandis que le "vous" désignerait (par le vouvoiement), le possible candidat au poste qui n'aurait donc pas lu les conseils dudit Kristof.

Voilà pour mon interprétation.

Comment: Ou bien le "nous" pourrait désigner le(s) journaliste(s) / la rédaction alors que le "vous" désignerait le lecteur.

Answer (score 1):

Le "vous" vise peut-être à montrer que l'auteur veut rester général : cette erreur pourrait coûter le poste à n'importe qui, éventuellement au lecteur, s'il était dans pareille situation. En revanche, le "nous" est employé car Kristof s'adressait directement au narrateur (et ses "comparses")...

Answer (score 0):

Le "nous" désigne la compagnie pour laquelle Kristof travaille. Il semble que Kristof développe quelque chose (un logiciel) pour une compagnie qui sera plus tard utilisé par les gens. 
Le vous réfère aux utilisateurs de ce logiciel.